# Change flights in Vienna and time of Austrian Airlines flight

Tags: transit, short-connections, vie

1. I booked a ticket from Brussels to Amman thru Vienna as a connection flight on the same airline, Austrian airlines. The first flight from Brussels to Vienna is S8172. It arrives at 8:50. The flight from Vienna to Amman has the flight number OS853. My agent told me the second flight departs at 10:20 on 7-8-2014 while the company website says it is 9:50. Which time is correct for the second flight: it is 9:50 or 10:20 on 7-8-2014?
2. If the departure time is 9:50, I will have one hour between two flights. Is that time enough to change planes? My nationality is Jordanian, a non-EU nationality.

Comment: I would definitely trust schedule info from the airline's website over your travel agent.  Also, I assume 7-8-2014 is August 7 (not July 8 which is already past)?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your flight numbers I believe that your first flight is actually a codeshare flight operated by Brussels Airlines.

However, Vienna airport is compact, and the airport website

http://www.viennaairport.com/en/passengers/arrival__departure/transfer

States that 25 minutes is plenty for a a transfer.

When you check in at Brussels you should make sure your luggage is tagged correctly to Amman.